# How to evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 C_{i-1} C_{n-i-2}$?

Tags: summation, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I'm evaluating the sum and I've gone through things below:

Consider $C_{-2}=0,C_{-1}=-1 \\$ where $C_n$ stands for the nth Catalan number
$$
S_n=∑_{i=1}^ni^2 C_{i-1} C_{n-i-2}=∑_{i=0}^ni^2 C_{i-1} C_{n-i-2}\\
∑_{n=0}^∞S_n t^n=∑_{n=0}^∞∑_{i=0}^ni^2 C_{i-1} C_{n-i-2} t^n\\
=∑_{n=0}^∞∑_{i=0}^∞i^2 C_{i-1} C_{n-2} t^{n+i}\\
=(∑_{i=0}^∞C_{i-1}t^i)(∑_{n=0}^∞n^2 C_{n-2} t^n)\\=t(-\sqrt{1-4t})(∑_{n=0}^∞(n+1)^2 C_{n-1}t^n)\\
=t(-\sqrt{1-4t})(∑_{n=0}^∞((n+2)(n+1)-(n+1)) C_{n-1}t^n)\\
=t(-\sqrt{1-4t})(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}∑_{n=0}^∞C_{n-1} t^{n+2}-\frac{d}{dt}∑_{n=0}^∞C_{n-1} t^{n+1})\\
=t(-\sqrt{1-4t})(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(-t^2 \sqrt{1-4t})-\frac{d}{dt}(-t\sqrt{1-4t}))\\
=t(-\sqrt{1-4t})(\frac{-36 t^2+ 14 t - 1}{(1 - 4 t)^{3/2}})
$$
And I don't know how to do the next step to find the expression of $S_n$ in the form of n.

Comment: Why does $i^2$ turn into $n^2$ from line $3$ to line $4$?

Comment: I replaced $i^2$ with $n^2$ since it doesn't changes the result.

Comment: Interesting sequence in title.

Comment: @lyx: Yes, I guess that's always the case when one writes an equals sign :-) My question was slightly more specifically: Why do you believe it doesn't change the result (since $C_{i-1}$ and $C_{n-2}$ are different coefficients if you swap $i$ and $n$)?

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that before. So I should try to evaluate this series again without turning $i^2$ into $n^2$, right?

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to see that the generating function of this sequence of numbers factorizes in two pieces that can be managed using the generating function of the Catalan numbers.

It is well known that if the sequence has the form

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$$

then the generating functions of these sequences defined respectively as $S/A/B(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (s/a/b)_n x^n$ are related by

$$S(x)=A(x)B(x)$$

Then, if we consider $a_k=k^2C_{k-1}~,~b_{k}=C_{k-2}$ it remains to calculate $A(x), B(x)$. Define the generating function for the Catalan numbers, which is known in closed form to be:

$$c(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$

Then we can express $A,B$ in terms of this and its derivatives as follows:

$$A(x)=x (x^2c(x))''-x(xc(x))'~~~,~~~ B(x)=-x+x^2c(x)$$

Then $S$ can be calculated explicitly:

$$S(x)=\frac{x^2(2x-1)}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-4x}+\frac{1}{(1-4x)^{3/2}}\right)$$

which can be easily reexpanded in series form by noting that

$$\frac{1}{(1-4x)^{3/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}C_{n+1}x^n$$

which after some algebraic manipulations can be rewritten in the form

$$S(x)=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n-1)^2}{2}C_{n-2}x^n-\sum_{n=3}^\infty 4^{n-3}x^n$$

which gives the final form $(S_0=S_1=0,S_2=-1):$

$$S_n=-4^{n-3}-\frac{(n-1)^2}{2}C_{n-2}~~,~~ n\geq 3$$

Comment: If I didn't get anything wrong, shouldn't $S(x)$ be $\frac{x^2(2x-1)}{2} (\frac{1}{1-4x}-\frac{1}{(1-4x)^\frac{3}{2}})$?

Comment: You do have it wrong. All the equalities for $S(x),S_n$ and the sum in question have been cross checked with Mathematica.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. Appreciated for your help.